# It is possible to change Win10 build from 18363 to build 18917 without adding the computer to the Insiders program?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My Windows version is Win10 Pro build 18363 version 1909.

I want to use WSL2 but it requires build 18917 and I don't know if there is a way to update to that build without activating the Windows Insider program and I don't want to add the computer to the Insider program anyways.

It is possible to change to build 18917 not adding the computer to the Insiders program?

Comment: If you do wish to use the Insider version, V2004 is very reliable at this point.

Comment: If WSL2 is by default included with release 1909, then, there must be something wrong because I have Ubuntu installed: [PS C:\> wsl -l                                                                                                          
Ubuntu-18.04 (Default)] and when I issue the command "PS C:\> wsl --set-default-version 2" I got the error message: "Invalid command line option: --set-default-version" But you have provided the answer to my original question and to troubleshoot why it is not working for me it will break the rules of this platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I was forced to change this answer due to discovering that WSL2 is not actually a feature of Windows 10 version 1909**. I would normally delete this answer but it was erroneously accepted by the author.

> I want to use WSL2 but it requires build 18917 and I don't know if there is a way to update to that build without activating the Windows Insider program and I don't want to add the computer to the Insider program anyways.

The bad news is Windows Subsystem 2 (WSL 2) is **not** a feature of `Windows 10 version 1909 so upgrading to a Insider Preview` build for `Windows 10 version 2004` is absolutely required at this time.

> It is possible to change to build 18917 not adding the computer to the Insiders program?

The only way to receive 18917.1000 is to change the release channel to that of Insider Preview.

Answer (score 2):

No. Latest build for Windows 10 pro is 18363 and that build above requires you to be in the Insider Program. One of my machines is an Insider machine